# Check if string in list present in HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code to find text in my parsed HTML:

```
searched_word = "News"
results = parsedHTML.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
if results:
    doStuff()
```

This works, but I'd like to use a list instead, e.g:

```
searched_words = ["News", "Team"]
```

And if my parsed HTML has any of these string elements in its contents, should return True and what element was found in the HTML. I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: `re.compile("|".join(searched_words))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help.

```
searched_words = ["News", "Team"]
pattern = re.compile("|".join(searched_words))
results = parsedHTML.body.find_all(string=pattern, recursive=True)
if results:
    doStuff()
```